# auto layout messing up my buttons. What I am doing wrong? one button is taking up more space than the other despite all constraints being equal?

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I have two buttons that have the same width and height.  One Button is on the top left of the screen, while the other is on the top right of the screen.  Here are the constraints:

left Button(colored Black):
Height 105, width 225,
align top to safe Area with 30 points,
align leading to safe area with 0 points.

Right Button(colored Blue):
height 105, width 225,
align top safe are with 30 points,
align trailing to safe area with 0 points.

shouldn't they be the same exact size?  why is the blue button taking up more space in smaller screens?[blue button takes up more space in smaller screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQFvC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Devices have different view widths...

A few examples:

```
iPhone 14 Plus      428
iPhone 14 Pro Max.  430
iPhone 14 Pro       393
iPhone 14           390
iPhone SE 3rd gen.  375
iPhone 13           390
iPhone 13 mini      375
```

You are setting each button width to `225` ... `225 + 225 = 450`

So, the buttons are the same size, but they are overlapping.

If you want two equal-width buttons, constrain them like this:

- blackButton.top to safeArea.top + 30
- blueButton.top to safeArea.top + 30
- blackButton.leading to safeArea.leading
- blueButton.trailing to safeArea.trailing

and, the key constraint:

- blueButton.width equalTo blackButton.width

Comment: Thank you!  A follow up question,  when creating constraints for objects, do you have to keep all devices widths in mind?  That would make sense but I never heard of that before.  I am still new to this thing.

Comment: @AA - User Interface design is a lot more than just dropping objects onto a rectangle. Is it a small phone? a big phone? an iPad? Is the device rotated to "Landscape" mode? etc. Do some searching for `adaptive layout`. In your specific example, we don't care about the device widths. We want two equal-width buttons. That's the whole point of constraints and auto-layout.