# Auto layout constraints adjust view sizes despite complete constraints

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have two buttons, button A on the left, and button B on the right, and a UIView below them.
Here are the constraints for all of them.

Button A Constraints:
Width 75, Height 35
Top 10 to safe area
Bottom 241 to uview(red color)
leading 10 to safe area
trailing 244 to button B(on the right)

Button B constraints:
Width 75, Height 35
Top 10 points to safe area
Bottom 241 to uiview(red)
trailing 10 to safe area
leading 244 to button A(on the left)
Width 75, Height 35

Constraints for UIView:
top 241 to the two buttons
bottom 0 to safe area
leading and trailing are both zero with respect to safe area, but the trailing keeps changing to superview with no options to edit that.

The big question I have is why is button A all the sudden getting bigger and moving taking up more space despite the width being fixed? Also, it should be 244 points away from button B.  What's up with that expansion? I gave it both x, y, width and height.  What's the issue?

I attached photos

[image: portraitimage]

[image: landscapeimage]

Comment: This looks a lot like your previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75394416/auto-layout-messing-up-my-buttons-what-i-am-doing-wrong-one-button-is-taking-u

Answer (score 0):

Auto layout needs some flexibility to adapt the layout to different screen sizes and orientations. If you have too few or too many constraints then it can't do this. In your case you have too many constraints.

You are setting the width of the buttons and you have a complete series of horizontal constraints `|-A-B-|`.

Now if the screen isn't exactly as wide as you have specified (10+75+244+75+10), which it won't be in landscape (or even in portrait on a different device) then something has to change, but there is no flexibility in your layout.

This means that auto layout has to break one of your constraints; you will be getting an error in the console when you run your app regarding conflicting constraints.

You need to decide what needs to remain fixed in your layout and where you can introduce flexibility.

What do you want to remain fixed?

- The space from the leading/trailing edge of the buttons?
- The space between buttons.
- The size of the buttons?

They can't all be fixed.

For example if the size and leading/trailing edge is to remain fixed then you get rid the 244 horizontal space between the buttons.

Or, you could allow the buttons to grow. Change their size constraints to be >=75.